# re-start celery queue after re-starting broker

Tags: redis, celery

I started my celery worker queue (in background):

```
celery worker -Q my_queue -l info
```

After this, its broker (`redis`) was stopped, and meanwhile the background `celery worker` keeps trying to re-connect to redis after **growing amount of time**.

Now my goal is re-start a **non-duplicate** `my_queue` after restarting redis. I realize that the following celery API will not return `my_queue` until the re-connection is made:

```
celery.task.control.inspect().active_queues()
```

Now if I start a new `my_queue`, I will end up with duplicate `my_queue` if the previous `celery worker` in the background is re-connected afterward.

A solution might be letting `celery worker` to actively quit if its broker is found stopped, but I don't find the right way to do this. I also don't want to kill it by previous-saved PID. Any suggestions or alternatives will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's contradictory to my requirement, but it seems that I do need the help from a PID file:

```
celery worker -Q my_queue -l info --pidfile=pid.log
```

which will raise an exception if the pid saved in pid.log is already running.

This is still not the ideal solution, and any suggestion regarding how to let `celery worker` actively quit if its broker is found stopped will still be appreciated.